# Custom Tab View like Google Chrome's

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am looking for this code but it does not have enough information

http://www.oschina.net/question/54100_29061

I need to attain that kind of tabs like tabs in google chrome that overlaps.

```
  <customview.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/frag_show_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/frag_productline_list" >
</customview.HorizontalListView>
```

So I am using horizontal list view + adapter and have -margin to the right but it's cut off. It doesnt need to be draggable, just the look

[image]